# MongoDb: sharded replica set: data distribution

Tags: mongodb

1. How does the data get distributed among the shards?
2. How to backup and restore an infrastructure with 2 shards (3 config servers and 1 mongos)
3. When should I choose MongoDb Shard with Replica Set vs MongoDb Replica set only?
4. I have 2 shards. I use mongodump and mongorestore for backup and restore, is it a good practice?
5. Sometimes, the 3 config server are out of sync. What does it mean? How can I quickly get rid of these issues?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the 3 config server are out of sync. What does it mean? How can I quickly get rid of these issues?

> *Most convenient way would be to copy (cp or rsync) the configdb data directory content between hosts in cases of inconsistency*

When should I choose MongoDb Shard with Replica Set vs MongoDb Replica set only?

> Replica ONLY: When you desire to make your mongo data highly available
>   and add redundancy in your solution. The benefit can be to offload
>   reporting requests to secondary nodes and/or make mongodb cluster
>   sustain network partitions or disaster recovery
>
> Sharding ONLY: When you desire to scale your mongodb cluster
>   horizontally to achieve load balancing and distribute traffic to
>   multiple hosts you must choose sharding. For example, you can achieve
>   partitioning benefits with sharding enabled on databases.
>
> Sharding with replica set: When you desire to enable all benefits
>   stated above i.e. scale you cluster horizontally to handle large
>   volumes of data for load balancing and also achieve HA within each
>   shard you must choose this approach